# Theorem 4.20 from baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ be a noncompact and bounded  set  in $\mathbb{R}^1$. Then there exists a continuous function on $E$ which is notuniformly continuous.

**Proof:**

"By condition there exists a limit point $x_0$ of $E$ which is not a point of $E$. Consider $$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x-x_0}\quad (x\in E).$$ This is continuous on $E$, but evidently unbounded. To see that $f(x)$ is not uniformly cintinuous, let $\varepsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ be arbitrary, and choose a point $x\in E$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Taking $t$ close enought to $x_0$, we can make the difference $|f(t)-f(x)|$ greater than $\varepsilon$, althought $|t-x|<\delta$. Since this is true for every $\delta>0$, $f$ is not uniformly continuous."

I have question:
$$|f(t)-f(x)|=\dfrac{|x-t|}{|x-x_0||t-x_0|}>\dfrac{|x-t|}{\delta|t-x_0|}. \qquad (*)$$ Because $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$ then we can choose $x\in E$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$.

Can anyone explain to me in $"\varepsilon-\delta"$ term that last $(*)$ will be great that $\varepsilon$?

I found some old posts but I can't understood them.

Comment: What means taking $t$ close enought to $x_0$? I can understand why it will be greater that $\varepsilon$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose $t$ within $|x - x_0|/2$ of $x_0$.  Then $|t -x| >  |x_0 - x| - |t-x_0| > |x_0 - x| / 2$.  With this you have $$ |f(t) - f(x)| > {1 \over 2|t-x_0|}. $$
Now if we let $t$ be within ${1 \over 4\epsilon}$ of $x_0$ (if it isn't already) you get $$ |f(t) - f(x)| > {1 \over 2/(4\epsilon)} = 2\epsilon. $$

Comment: First of all you take $t$ from neighborhood of $x_0$ with radius $|x-x_0|/2$. Right? Then you take $t$ from $N_{1/4\varepsilon}(x_0)$. Why? What is $\varepsilon$?

Comment: $\epsilon$ is a small constant; I'm using it as in your post ($\epsilon = \varepsilon$).  To show the failure of uniform continuity you want to show that for some $\epsilon > 0$, you cannot choose a $\delta >0$ so that
$$ |x-t| < \delta ~ \Rightarrow ~ |f(x) - f(t)|< \epsilon. $$

Comment: why did you choose $t$ two times?

Comment: Choosing $t$ so that $|t - x_0| < \min \{ |x-x_0|/2, 1/4\epsilon \}$ allows us to employ the two lower bounds we need in $(*)$.  I could have written it out using the $\min$ function, but people often choose a constant and later say ``well, if we needed to pick it a little smaller before let's assume we did."

Comment: On short proofs like this that makes it easier to digest each step separately, although if you do that too much it can also make a reader wonder whether all the necessary conditions can be met at once.  In our proof, taking $t$ closer to $x_0$ is always a safe move.

Comment: Did we use somewhere that it's unbounded?

Comment: We use the *boundedness* of $E$ to say that the sequence is converging to a limit ($x_0$) that is a point in $\mathbb{R}$ (as opposed to a sequence going to infinity).  This allows us to put $t$ in a small neighborhood of the limit point, $x_0$.

Comment: I little edited a solution of problem. So $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$. Then exists $x\in E$ s.t. $0<|x-x_0|<\delta/2$. Also exists $y\in E$ s.t. $0<|y-x_0|<|x-x_0|/2$. By triangle inequality $|y-x|\leqslant |y-x_0|+|x_0-x|<2|x_0-x|<\delta$.  Also $|x-y|>|x-x_0|-|y-x_0|>|y-x_0|$. Hence $|f(y)-f(x)|>\dfrac{1}{|x-x_0|}$. Taking $\varepsilon=2$ and arbitrary $\delta\in (0,1)$ hence $|f(y)-f(x)|>\dfrac{1}{|x-x_0|}>2/{\delta}>2$. If this true for $\delta<1$ then it'll be true for $\delta\geqslant 1$ because $\exists x,y \in E$ s.t. $|y-x|<\dfrac{1}{\delta}\leqslant \delta$ and so on.

Comment: Am I right in above post?

Comment: There are some problems with your comment, but the main thing you should do differently is use the bound $|x-y| > |x-x_0| - |y-x_0| > {1\over 2}|x-x_0|$.  This way we get $|f(x) - f(y)| > {1 \over 2|y - x_0|}$ and can take $y$ closer and closer to $x_0$ to achieve any desired lower bound.  This is important because we cannot necessarily move $x$ towards $x_0$ without undoing the previous assumption $|x-x_0| > 2|y-x_0|$.

Comment: Why we can't move $x$ towards $x_0$ without undoing the previous assumption?

Comment: I think that all is OK. Why?  I don't take take $x$ close to $x_0$. I am only applying estimate $|x-x_0|<\delta/2$